# t-sql get all period of date from a date, a periods and a number of periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, period

I have a SQLServer table with the columns : a date, a period, and the number of period.
And i want to get the dates in every period of month.

Sample in my first line i have :

- Date : 25/01/2020
- Period of month (always in month) : 3
- Number of Periods : 4

I should have (1 line per Date) :

- 25/01/2020
- 25/04/2020
- 25/07/2020
- 25/10/2020
- 25/01/2021

I have thought about doing a cross join with a calendar table but since the period and the day of the date are not always the same, i can't think a easy solution.

if anyone has an advice.

Comment: So, do you have three columns, and the second column (number of periods) is always in months? Which is the enviroment in which you are running SQL?

Comment: Yes the 2nd column (number of periods) is always in month, and i use sql server. (Sorry, i just add the precision.)

Comment: And do you want to have all the derivate dates on different columns like Date2, Date3, Date4, Date5?

Comment: No, i would like to have in different line if possible : Line 1 : Date1   | Line 2 : Date2 | ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is an easier way, but this works:

```
Create table temp_dummy
(Startdate date,
numper int,
per int)
go

insert into temp_dummy values(CONVERT(DATETIME,'25/01/2020',103),3,4)



Select dateadd(month,a.numper*num_row,a.Startdate) from
(
Select top(Select td.per from temp_dummy td) td1.Startdate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by td1.Startdate ) AS num_row, td1.per, td1.numper
from temp_dummy td1
cross join sys.tables
)
a
```

Comment: Thanks i just try it and it's work ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you need more than 100 periods - just add another cross join:

```
Declare @myDate date = '2020-01-25'
      , @myPeriod int = 3
      , @numberPeriods int = 4;

   With t (n)
     As (
 Select t.n
   From (Values (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) As t(n)
        )
 Select Top (@numberPeriods + 1)
        PeriodDate = dateadd(month, (row_number() over(Order By @@spid) - 1) * @myPeriod, @myDate)
   From t t1, t t2;
```

If you have a limit to the number of periods - you could use values directly instead of the cross join.

```
 Select Top (@numberPeriods + 1)
        PeriodDate = dateadd(month, t.n * @myPeriod, @myDate)
   From (Values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) As t(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have a solution, maybe not the best (with recurcive sql).

```
WITH Dates(_date,_dtmax,_Nbperiod) AS 
(
    SELECT myDate as dt, DATEADD(MONTH,NbPeriod*Period,myDate) as dtMax ,NbPeriod 'NbPeriod'
    FROM myTable a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, _Nbperiod, _date) as Date) as dt,  _dtmax as dtMax,  _Nbperiod as NbPeriod 
    FROM Dates
    WHERE CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, _Nbperiod, _date) as Date) < _dtmax
)
SELECT* FROM dates;
```